# Populate table using VBA/Formulas

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to remove manual data entry and duplicate from a process.  I have a report that is exported to excel and I'm trying to merge it with a prebuilt data set.  I've tried the basic vlookup and if formulas.  Where I am running into trouble is Column D lists an activity which may or may not be leave.  When it is leave, I need the value returned to Column N and the Row corresponding to date and ID for that employee.  Is this something that is even possible?

[Sample Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K1Lhe.png)

Comment: Try =SUMIF(D1:D9,"=leave",E1:E9).  Does that do what you want?

Comment: You say you want a value returned in column N if column D is leave but what value do you want returned in column N? also, you want the row corresponding to date and ID, where do you want this displayed?

Comment: Sorry, ignore my first question, just saw your 'Sample Data'

Comment: So, when you input the employee # in L5, you want the Activity that is a leave for any date from column D in M5? Can you explicit what values you want on row L? The headers from E:G are masked and don't seem to match headers in your header on rows K3/4 and on.